# Oracle 12 C - Months_between function is providing 18 months when Start date is June 30 2020 to End date is Dec 31st 2021

Tags: oracle12c

Oracle 12 C - Months_between function is providing 18 months when Start date is June 30th 2020 to End date is Dec 31st 2021. Actual result should be 18 months 1 day.

Please suggest on the function name and details to be used in order to get the actual result (18 months 1 say) in Oracle 12 C.

select MONTHS_BETWEEN(date '2021-12-31',date '2020-06-30') from dual;
Provides answer as 18. But it should have been or we want 18 months 1 day (like 18.03) in Oracle 12C.

Please let me know whether is there a function in Oracle 12C to get 18 months 1 day when Start date is June 30th 2020 to End date is Dec 31st 2021.

Comment: What result would you want to get for dates `date '2020-01-31'` and `date '2020-04-30'`? Hint: February. Hint 2: leap years. From my point of view, correct result for your example is 18 months, not 18 months + 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

"18" is the correct result. From the [documentation for MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions114.htm#SQLRF00669):

> If date1 and date2 are either the same days of the month or both last
>   days of months, then the result is always an integer.

Comment: Thank you. But please let me know whether is there a function in Oracle 12 C to provide 18 months 1 day or 18.03 when Start date is June 30th 2020 to End date is Dec 31st 2021.

Comment: There is not. Because not all months have the same number of days, and February doesn't even have the same number of days internally from year to year, the last day of the month to last day of the month should always be an integer, not one month plus one day. If you want the difference in days, then measure that.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a function to find out the difference in days between 2 dates in Oracle 12 C.? Please let me know.

Comment: If the datatype is "date" (not timestamp) you can just subtract one from the other and the difference will be measured in days. That said, what about '01-JAN-2020' and '01-FEB-2020', or '01-FEB-2020' to '01-MAR-2020'? Each of these intervals should also be "one month", even though the number of days is different. Your calculation seems to be premised on the idea that a month can never exceed 30 days, which is false, or June 30 to December 31 would be 18 months and 8 days (10 months with 31 days and 1 with 28). Why would 31 days in a month be acceptable for 9 months, but not in the last month?

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day!

Comment: We have 11 month with 31 days,6 months with 30 days,1 month with 28 days and 1 day (30th of June).

Comment: the difference from 30-June to 31-July is one month, not one month and one day, as both are the last day of their respective months. the difference from 01-June to 01-July would also be one month. 29-June to 31-July would be one month and one day, as would 01-June to 02-July.